# Cookies are sent from server in local environment (localhost) but not in production

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I am using express-session to manage session. And here is the config.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
    store: new connectMongo({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
      ttl: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      autoRemove: 'native',
    }),
  }),
);
```

And here is the login route handler fucntion on server side.

```
const LogIn = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      email,
    });
    const passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordIsValid) {
      throw new Error('Password is invalid');
    }
    req.session.userId = user._id;
    return res.status(200).send({
      id: user._id,
      email: user.email,
    });
}
```

This code sends cookie over to the browser in localhost environment but not in production.

Help me figure out the reason. Thank you in advance!